# How to automatically delete old Google App Engine version instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, docker

I'm experimenting with more cost effective ways to deploy my Rails apps, and went through the [Ruby Starter Projects](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/hello-world) to get a feel for Google Cloud Platform.

It's *almost* perfect, and certainly competitive on price, but I can't figure out how to automatically delete old deployed version instances after redeploying.

ie: let's say I have one version of each instance running:

[image: Compute Engine -> VM Instances]

And then I make a change to my app and redeploy with:

```
$ gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml worker.yaml --promote
```

So now I have *two* versions of each instance deployed (as Google switches between them intelligently, I'd assume):

[image: Compute Engine -> VM Instances have doubled]

But now what? Will these instances ever turn off by themselves? The best way I've found of getting rid of them so far is from [the tutorial's Deleting the project page](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/delete-tutorial-resources):

> Deleting app versions
>
> You can find the list of your app versions in the [Versions page](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/appengine/versions). To delete the non-default versions, select the check boxes and then click **Delete**.

[image: appengine/versions]

Is everyone on Google App Engine just manually deleting the old deployments of their apps?

Comment: Automatic stopping of non-default VMs has been mentioned on the mailing-lists (or release notes?) as a future-thing. For now, you have to do it manually.

Comment: @greg as it seems to evolve quickly, any updates on this one ?

Comment: Nothing that does automatically. You need to write a bash script in order to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To stop all instances of all non-default versions of all modules (independently of what languages those modules are in), you could add a small `control` module, written in Python, using the `modules` API:

```
from google.appengine.api.modules import modules

# core logic (inside a cron or other handler)
for m in modules.get_modules():
    dv = modules.get_default_version(m)
    for v in modules.get_versions(m):
        if v != dv: modules.stop_version(m, v)
```

This doesn't *delete* the non-default versions (the `modules` API does not appear to currently support deletion), but does ensure that none of their instances are running (so no charges would be incurred for them).

This core logic is meant for you to wrap it inside a handler, so you can trigger it as required, for example in a cron job, or in a "regular" handler that you trigger from the outside (with appropriate auth) e.g. via wget or curl within your bash scripts.

I don't believe there's a Ruby version of Python's `google.appengine.api.modules.modules` , but, I could be wrong... I just couldn't find one. However, a simple Python-coded module should let you control modules coded in whatever other App Engine language (since App Engine lets you mix and match modules coded in different languages).

Comment: Oh neat - I can make that work. I should be able to build that into my deploy script. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: This is mind blowing that this is even an issue--it didn't used to be!  Is there a valid reason to have instances running for versions that aren't serving traffic?  Why google, why?

Comment: does anyone now what is the pip install command for using modules API?

Answer (score 17):

Just to throw my solution here after reading all the others provided:

```
gcloud app versions list --format="value(version.id)" --sort-by="~version.createTime" | tail -n +6 | xargs -r gcloud app versions delete --quiet
```

Main benefit is that it can still run successfully even if theres 5 or less existing versions.

Comment: This is the best solution, only using the command line to solve it!

Comment: Getting an empty output after `tail -n +6`

Comment: I added `--service=default` so that multiple services are listed and deleted separately and each retains 6 old versions.

Answer (score 16):

We deploy an App Engine instance from Cloud Build, which is a common deployment pattern. At the end of the cloudbuild.yaml, we specify the following commands as the last build step, which deletes every version except the last 5 versions:

```
versions=$(gcloud app versions list \
  --service default \
  --sort-by '~VERSION.ID' \
  --format 'value(VERSION.ID)' | sed 1,5d)
for version in $versions; do
  gcloud app versions delete "$version" \
    --service default \
    --quiet
done
```

Answer (score 10):

The following removes all version except 5 most recent:
Uses `ghead` (on macOS, `brew install coreutils`), replace with `head` for linux.

```
gcloud app versions delete `gcloud app versions list | sed 's/  */:/g' | cut -f 2 -d : | tail -n +2 | ghead -n -5 | tr "\n" " "`
```

Comment: The `gcloud` command supports formatting and filtering of results. To remove all versions older than 2 weeks ``gcloud app versions delete --quiet `gcloud app versions list --format="value(id)[terminator=' ']" --filter="version.createTime<-P2W"` NONE``

Comment: @Richard Johnson is there a way to filter gloud results to select all versions other than the latest 5 as Gabriel does in his answer ? otherwise, this does not really answer the question does it ?

Comment: Also using this script (or Richar's one) I'm getting the error `ERROR: (gcloud.app.versions.delete) The default service (module) may not be deleted, and must comprise at least one version.` Since I have microservices, I need to select the N oldest versions for each app service, can this be done easily ?

Comment: Can this be tweaked to not throw error `the default service may not be deleted`?

Answer (score 4):

For those not familiar with xargs syntax, I took the very nice answer from @bkanuka and split it in two lines. It keeps last 5 versions and works even if there is less than 5 versions deployed:

```sh
    VERSIONS=$(gcloud app versions list --format="value(version.id)" --sort-by="~version.createTime" | tail -n +6 )
    gcloud app versions delete --quiet $VERSIONS
```

Comment: Great! Also better add `--service=default` in case you have more than one service or the versions are all intermixed in the list.

Comment: @Matt Byrne: I think your comment is not relevant. gcloud supports deleting several versions in one call i.e. "gcloud app versions delete v1 v2" without looping. Adding back xargs will make it more difficult to read, and will make n calls so it is likely to be slower.

Comment: @Mapad - you are right. I'm not sure why I needed to do that at the time. I've deleted my comment that suggested `echo | xargs` so others won't get confused. Also as @intotecho suggested, it's better to be explicit about the version. We add the following `--service=default --filter="traffic_split=0"`, the second one ensuring we exclude any versions with active traffic split as they are still in use.

Answer (score 3):

The command below may work:

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml worker.yaml --promote --stop-previous-version
```

see: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy

I cannot find any documents about the default values of `promote` and `stop-previous-version`. As far as I observed, `promote` is `True` and `stop-previous-version` is `False` though.
I wrote both options for safety.

Comment: This does not work. I have tried it and still instances are running for the past versions.

Comment: @user10314103 Maybe you use auto-scaling? Then it is ignored. "Note that if the version is running on an instance of an auto-scaled service in the App Engine Standard environment, using --stop-previous-version will not work and the previous version will continue to run because auto-scaled service instances are always running."

Answer (score 0):

To turn off the instances associated with older versions you could try to use the teardown scripts (eventually customised) mentioned in the [delete tutorial resources doc](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/delete-tutorial-resources):

> If you tried the tutorial about how to run Ruby on Compute Engine, see
>   the [Deployment and teardown scripts](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/run-on-compute-engine#deployment_and_teardown_scripts) section of that tutorial

Careful with deleting the app, though, you can't re-use the app id!

Since the older versions are no longer the default ones at least no new instances will be automatically starting for them. You may still need to delete them manually, unless Google automatically deletes the older automatically assigned versions exceeding the max number of versions allowed for an app.

Answer (score 0):

We created a little Python script to delete old versions automagically. We run it before every deploy so that our deploys always succeed (and never fail due to having too many versions deployed already).

https://pypi.org/project/appengine-clean/

Answer (score 0):

Using [zx](https://github.com/google/zx), you can write it with relatively clean code.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env zx

// firstly, deploy
await $`gcloud app deploy --quiet --project=XXX`

// secondly, delete versions except the one deployed just now
let versions = await $`gcloud app versions list --project=XXX | sed 's/  */:/g' | cut -f 2 -d : | tail -n +2 | ghead -n -1`
console.log("---")

versions = versions.toString().split("\n") // makes array
versions.pop() // removes last blank element created by new line
console.log(versions)

await Promise.all(versions.map(version =>
    $`gcloud app versions delete ${version} --project=XXX`
))
console.log("done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete all of the versions except the active version's instances, you can use these commands:

```bash
versions_with_traffic=$(gcloud app versions list --hide-no-traffic --format="value(version.id)")

versions_to_be_deleted=$(gcloud app versions list --format="value(version.id)" | grep -v $versions_with_traffic)

gcloud app versions delete $versions_to_be_deleted --quiet

# if you need to delete multiple versions, then you need:
echo $versions_to_be_deleted | gcloud app versions delete --quiet
```

I believe the variable names are self-explanatory. However, if you still need help, please continue reading.

1. Get all of the version numbers with active traffic
2. Use `grep -v` to negate the original list, so that we can get the list of inactive version numbers
3. Delete the versions

You could also add the `service=${service_name}` filter in the command if you have multiple services.

For instance:

```bash
versions_with_traffic=$(gcloud app versions list --hide-no-traffic --service=default --format="value(version.id)")

versions_with_traffic=$(gcloud app versions list --hide-no-traffic --service=worker --format="value(version.id)")
```

Tips:

- You could add these scripts to your CI pipeline, so these gets cleaned up every deployment

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is kina old problem, but for someone who is still dealing with this, this is my solution in ruby

The code below will find all services (in all project provided in the array) and keep only the last 5 versions for each

```
keep_versions = 5

["project1", "project2"].each do |project|

    puts "Project: #{project}"

    services_output = `gcloud app --project=#{project} versions list --format="value(service)"`
    unique_service = services_output.split("\n").uniq

    unique_service.each do |service|
        output = `gcloud app --project=#{project} versions list --service=#{service} --sort-by="~version.createTime" --format="value(version.id)"`
        version_ids = output.split("\n")

        if version_ids.count <= keep_versions
            puts "  Service: #{service} has #{version_ids.count} version(s) which is less than or equal to #{keep_versions}"
            next
        end
        version_ids = version_ids[keep_versions..-1]
        version_ids_str = version_ids.join(" ")
        if version_ids.any?
            puts "  Service: #{service} deleting #{version_ids.count} version(s)"
            system("gcloud app --project=#{project} versions delete #{version_ids_str} --quiet")
        end
    end
end
```